# How to move system to a new, smaller drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, lvm

I have a 320G HDD(has a lot of free space), but planning to move my system to a smaller 275G SSD.
How can i do it without loosing data?
fdisk -l output

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3ADBB6B9-D132-427F-B2C5-9D3666CDB354

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    411647    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2   411648   2508799   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2508800 625141759 622632960 296.9G Linux LVM




Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 7.8 GiB, 8317304832 bytes, 16244736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 189.1 GiB, 203092393984 bytes, 396664832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

pvs output

```
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 
  /dev/sda3  fedora lvm2 a--  296.89g 50.00g
```

vgs output

```
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 
  fedora   1   3   0 wz--n- 296.89g 50.00g
```

lvs output

```
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home fedora -wi-ao---- 189.14g                                                    
  root fedora -wi-ao----  50.00g                                                    
  swap fedora -wi-ao----  <7.75g
```

parted -l output

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      211MB   1285MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1285MB  320GB   319GB                                      lvm
```

Tried to do it with clonezilla, but failed because target drive is smaller

Answer (score 1):

I've alwayes used [GParted](https://gparted.org/) [live CD/USB](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) for this kind of tasks.

After booting, first *shrink* the existing LVM volumes to the needed sizes
(i.e. the size I want on the destination disk). Open a terminal and do (you might need sudo, I can't remember from memory!):

```
lvresize --verbose --resizefs -L NEWSIZE /dev/mapper/fedora-home
```

probably you need to shrink just the `home` partition, really. Don't forget to resize the physical volume, too:

```
pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize {some-space} /dev/sda3
```

Then do a simple copy/paste of the relevant partitions from the old to the new disk.

As an added bonus, `GParted` keeps the same UUIDs of the partitions from the old disk.

Comment: But the problem is LVM, i can't shrink an LVM physical volume

Comment: @George yes, sorry, I missed the `lvm` part. It should be actually doable via cli. I'll update my answer.